# Cannot acces WorkManager (WorkManagerTaskExecutor) JDK 1.8 Spring 4.2..5

Tags: java, spring, maven

Am using jdk 1.8 with spring 4.2.5 release, my project getting failure on maven compilation

**Error : Cannot access WorkManager** (org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor

I have added the dependency too in my pom.xml
Advanced thanks

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
<version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
```

Error on Compilation
[

```
ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure

MyjavaClass.java:[43,7] error: cannot access WorkManager


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Compilation failure
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:715)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:429)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        ... 17 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

in my java class

```
@Autowired
WorkManagerTaskExecutor wrkManager;


wrkManager.execute(runnable) ----- here were it says cannot access workManager
```

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: You should be auto wiring a `TaskExecutor` and not a `WorkManagerTaskExecutor` and you should read the exception. It says it cannot access the `WorkManager` NOT the `WorkManagerTaskExecutor`. Which means you don't have the work manager api on your classpath.

Comment: The same code works well with JDK 1.6 environment. When try to upgrade JDK 1.8 with spring 4.2.5 its not working.

Comment: Is this issue resolved?
If Yes, How?

Answer (score 1):

The [Compatibility Guide for JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html) states a change in the java compiler (javac) in java 1.8. The details can be found in the synopsis "Interfaces need to be present when compiling against their implementations" in this document. So the classes with the missing interfaces have to be added to the classpath during the compile process when using JDK 8.

Answer (score 0):

I have added this dependency to fix the issue.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.ws.prereq</groupId>
            <artifactId>commonj-twm</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```